# A question about $|X|\le d(X)^{\chi(X)}$

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

It is well known that the following cardinal inequality $|X|\le d(X)^{\chi(X)}$
holds,
where $d(X)$ denotes *density* of $X$ and $\chi(X)$ denotes *character* of $X$.

Thus we have

> **$|X|\le d(X)^\omega$ if $X$ is first countable.**

My question is this:

> **In the above conclusion, could the condition "first countable" be replaced by "countable tightness and countable pseudocharacter"?, i.e., do we have 
>   $|X| \le d(X)^\omega$ if $X$ has countable tightness and countable pseudocharacter?**

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Are you assuming any separation axioms?

Comment: It's true for Lindelöf spaces, due to a standard generalisation of Arhangel'skij's theorem. Is that the motivation for your question?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $X$ could be Hausdorff, regular, or Tychonoff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now do have an argument for what you originally asked:

Assume $X$ is $T_3$ and has countable tightness and pseudocharacter.
Let $D$ be a dense subset of size $d(X)$.
As each $x \in X$ is in $\overline{D}$, and $X$ has countable tightness 
we can choose for each $x \in X$ a countable subset $D_x$ of $D$ such that
$x \in \overline{D_x}$.

As $X$ has countable pseudocharacter, and is regular, we can pick for each $x$ a countable sequence $(U_n(x))$ of open sets such that $$\{x\} = \bigcap_n \overline{U_n(x)}\text{.}$$

Now define $$f: X \rightarrow ([D]^\omega)^\omega \text{ by } f(x) = (U_n(x) \cap D_x)_{n \in \omega}$$

Claim: $f$ is 1-1. For suppose $x \neq y$. Then there exists an $n$ such that $y \notin \overline{U_n(x)}$. As clearly for any $n$, $y \in \overline{U_n(y) \cap D_y}$ ,we see that for that first $n$: $$y \notin \overline{U_n(x) \cap D_x} \subseteq \overline{U_n(x)} \text{ but } y \in \overline{U_n(y) \cap D_y}$$

meaning that $f(x)_n \neq f(y)_n$ (the closures of these sets are different so the sets are different too) so $f(x) \neq f(y)$.

As $|([D]^\omega)^\omega| = |D^\omega| = d(X)^\omega$, we have that $|X| \le d(X)^\omega$ for those spaces.

Analysing the proof we see that in fact that for regular spaces $X$:

$$|X| \le d(X)^{t(X)\psi(X)}$$

using sequences of length $\psi(X)$ of subsets of $D$ of size $t(X)$. As $t(X)\psi(X) \le \chi(X)$, this indeed generalises you original $d(X)^{\chi(X)}$ bound for $|X|$.

(after some thought on necessity of $T_3$-ness):

Define $X = \{\mathscr{F}: \mathscr{F} \text {a free ultrafilter on }\omega\} \cup \omega$. It is well known that $|X| \ge 2^\mathfrak{c}$. Define a topology by local bases: all $n \in \omega$ are isolated, while a neighbourhood of $\mathscr{F}$ is of the form $\{\mathscr{F}\} \cup A$, where $A \in \mathscr{F}$. It's I( I think ) easy to check that $X$ is Hausdorff, $t(X) = \omega = \psi(X)  =d(X)$, but $X$ does not obey the bound. So $X$ cannot be regular, in fact. (The proven bound actually shows this, it's similar to using Jones' lemma to show non-normality of spaces).

Comment: So, the regularity is not necessary?

Comment: @Paul maybe not. Can you show 1-1 ness of $f$ with just $\bigcap_n U_n(x)  =\{x\}$ as a  given? The other answer on the other maths forum suggested this, I think. But regularity is not very stong as a condition in theorems like this, it's quite common. See Juhasz books on cardinal functions., e.g.

Comment: I will take time to think it. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Paul you're welcome , glad I could help. Post the 1-1 argument if you come up  with it.

Comment: @Paul I think I have a counter example when $T_3$ is weakened to $T_2$ see edit

Comment: @Paul This example at least shows that $d(X)^{\chi(X)}$ is sharp as well (for non-countable $\chi(X)$, as $\chi(X) = \mathfrak{c}$, for countable $\chi(X)$ take $\mathbb{R}$) . The character bound I think requires $T_1$-ness at least (or consider the included point topology!), weakening $\chi(X)$ to $\psi(X)t(X)$  needs something extra (In this case $T_1$ becomes $T_3$)

Comment: Re; Last paragraph. If  $|S|=k\geq \omega$, the set of free ultrafilters on $S$ has cardinal $2^{2^k}$... If $F_1$ and $F_2$ are unequal free ultrafilters on $\omega$   there are disjoint subsets $A_1,A_2$ of $\omega$ with $A_1\in F_1$ and $A_2\in F_2$, so the nbhds  $\{F_1\}\cap A_1$, $\{F_2\}\cup A_2$ are disjoint.  Also  $\{n\}$ is 
 clopen   for $n\in \omega$. So $X$ is $T_2$.... If $F\in X$ \ $\omega$  then $ \{F\}=\cap_{n\in \omega}\{F\}\cup (\omega$ \ $\{n\})$ ( so $ \psi (X)=\omega$), and if $F\in \bar S$ \ $S$ then $S\subset  \omega$ so $\tau(X)=\omega. $ So it IS easy.

Comment: @user254665 not everybody knows such facts about ultrafilters, it depends on your background.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks very much for your comments. Here I give an argument to prove $f$ is 1-1 by only using $T_2$. I don't know where my proof is wrong. Could you henp me?Fix any two distinct points $a, b \in \overline{D}$.
Suppose that $U(a), U(b)$ are two open neighbourhoods of $a$ and $b$ respectively such that
$U(a) \cap U(b)=\emptyset$, since $X$ is Hausdorff.
Thus $a \notin  \overline{ U(b) \cap U_n(a) \cap D_a}$,
but $b \in  \overline{ U(b) \cap U_n(b) \cap D_b}$.
This shows that $U_n(a) \cap D_a \not= U_n(b) \cap D_b$ for any $n\in \omega$, hence $f(a) \not= f(b)$.

Comment: @Paul if two sets are different after intersection with two disjoint sets, it does not mean these sets are different to start with.  Consider the sets $\mathh{Q} \cap (0,1)$ and $\matbb{Q} \cap (2,3)$. They are clearly different but $\matbb{Q} =\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @HennoBrandsma but $U_n(a) \cap D_a$, $U_n(b) \cap D_b$ interect with the same set $U(b)$.

Comment: You haven't shown the closures are different. @Paul you just found two different points that are not in resp. in the set. You need one point to be in the closure of one and not in the closure of the other.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Okay. I find that I have made a ridiculous mistake! Thank you!